# How to get email address in FB connect?

Tags: facebook

Can we get email address using: `users.getStandardinfo`?

Please help me on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't. But you can ask the user to provide it when he/she logs in.

There is proxied_email that can be taken from user table, you can try:

```
$personArray = $facebook->api_client->users_getInfo( $fb_config->user_id, "last_name, first_name, birthday, hometown_location, current_location, is_app_user, proxied_email" );
$email = $personArray[0]['proxied_email'];
if(empty($email)){
    echo 'Proxied email was not retreived. Trying fql query...';
    $facebookFQLResultXml = $facebook->api_client->fql_query("SELECT proxied_email FROM user WHERE uid=".$fb_config->user_id);
    $email = $facebookFQLResultXml['proxied_email'];
}
```

But I am not sure for the result

So you can get the proxied email and contact the user through it but you
can't extract the original email:

```
proxied_email - A proxied wrapper alternative for contacting the user through email,
```

instead of directly calling notifications.sendEmail. If the user shared his or her proxied
email address with you, this address also appears in the email field (see below).

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.getInfo

Comment: but how http://www.formspring.me (Sign up with Facebook), is fetching email address?